# Splitting list into sublists based off string value

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to Mathematica so please bare with me!

I wish to split an imported data list off of {x,y} values based off the y value, and then sum the corresponding parts.

An example of the imported list:

```
MyDataList = {{{20, "a"}, {3, "a"}, {4,"a"}, {6, "b"}, {10, "a"}, {12, "b"}, {2, "a"}}}
```

I want to make 2 sublists e.g.:

```
AList = {{20, "a"}, {3, "a"}, {4,"a"},{10, "a"},{2, "a"}}
BList = {{6,"b"},{12,"b"}}
```

And then sum the numerical parts of the list, e.g.:

```
AList = 39
Blist = 18
```

I've tried `GatherBy` and `SplitBy` to try and partition but it doesn't quite split how I need. Any advice would be super helpful!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html). Note `GroupBy` returns an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html).

With

```
myDataList = {{{20, "a"}, {3, "a"}, {4, "a"}, {6, "b"}, {10, "a"}, {12, "b"}, {2, "a"}}};
```

Then

```
res = GroupBy[First@myDataList, Last -> First, Total]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 39, "b" -> 18|>
> ```

and

```
res["a"]
```

> ```
> 39
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Your list is wrapped in another list, so you can use `First` to remove the outer list.

```
{AList, BList} = GatherBy[First@MyDataList, Last];

Total[First /@ AList]
(* 39 *)

Total[First /@ BList]
(* 18 *)
```

Comment: Hi, when I try that it returns, Lists {Alist,Blist} and {MyDataList} are not the same shape?

Comment: Then you must have changed something in your code. I used exactly the same ``MyDataList`` as you provided in the question, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Reap`/`Sow`:**

```
Last@Reap@Scan[Sow[First@#, Last@#] &, MyDataList, {2}] // Map[Total]
```

---

**Using `Merge`:**

```
Rule @@@ (Reverse /@ First@MyDataList) // Merge[#, Total] & // Values
```

---

Result:

> {39, 18}